# What is the scientific name of this tree?

Tags: species-identification, botany

- The tree flowers prior to the monsoon season and sheds it's leaves in Winter and regrow them in Spring and Summer.
- I have seen three different colours of the flower (growing in my neighbourhood): pink, violet and white.
- Place-India, Kolkata, West Bengal. Season - Monsoon.

[image: a twig]
[image: the tree]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Lagerstroemia, perhaps Lagerstroemia indica, the common crape myrtle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagerstroemia

Myrtle in french means blueberry: "From Medieval Latin myrtillus, diminutive of Latin myrtus (“myrtle”), from Semitic: Arabic مُرّ‎ (murr, “bitter”), Hebrew מֹר‎ (mor, “bitterness") ." Myrtle is an unrelated family with tough spicy seed pods which are used as a condiment including eucalyptus.

Crape, refers to the frilly flowers, from Latin Crispus, Crispy: frilly, crèpe is often used to refer to frilly fabric and it also means pancake in french, which is a chapatti with butter and milk and an egg from the bible.

Because you said it is common, I checked google images for "india frilled pink flower tree", it was about 20 images in. There should be a Hindi/Indian script of the wiki page, with the Indian derived name.

Comment: I found two of them today in south france here, where temperatures reach -15 some years: https://goo.gl/maps/xM3sFJe5bpC2